# How to slightly modify an inherited attribute from parent __init__() with minimal changes in the child class in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance, initialization

The code as below:

```
def some_function1():
    pass

def some_function2():
    pass

def some_function3():
    pass

def some_function4():
    pass

class ReporterClass():
    def __init__(self, data_reporter):
        self.data_reporter = data_reporter

class ParentClass():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.datacollector = ReporterClass(data_reporter={
            'Report info 1': some_function1,
            'Report info 2': some_function2,
            'Report info 3': some_function3,
            })

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.datacollector = ReporterClass(data_reporter={
            'Report info 1': some_function1,
            'Report info 2': some_function2,
            'Report info 3': some_function3,
            'Report info 4': some_function4,
            })
```

This works fine in this toy example, but the problem I have in the actual code is that there are many parameters in the `__init__()`, for example, `param1`... `param100`. Similarly, there are many dictionary items within `data_reporter`, for example, `Report info 1` ... `Report info 100`. I like to simply modify by adding `'Report info 4': some_function4` to the `self.datacollector` in the `ChildClass` without having to completely overwrite the parent's `__init__()` and having to repeat all the parameter code. Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

--- Edits ---

To explain more in detail. Based on the suggestions, I would create the child class as `ChildClass1`. However, my class has many parameters in the initialization. Not only I need to write them all in child class' `__init__()`, I also need to "repeat" them in the `super().__init__()`. So I am wondering if there is a more convenient and elegant way to not have to repeat themselves. Something like the `ChildClass2`?

```
class ChildClass1(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, 
                        param1, 
                        param2,
                        ., # Very long list of parameters
                        .,
                        .,
                        param100,
    ):
        super().__init__(
                        param1, 
                        param2,
                        ., # Very long list of parameters
                        .,
                        .,
                        param100
                        )
        self.datacollector.data_reporter['Report info 4'] = some_function4

class ChildClass2(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        some_var_to_store_parent_init_params = super().__init__.attr

        for param in some_var_to_store_parent_init_params:
            # somehow assign it back to ChildClass' args

        super().__init__(some_var_to_store_parent_init_params)

        self.datacollector.data_reporter['Report info 4'] = some_function4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `super()__init__()` will help you make good reuse of the parent `__init__`; then you can add the necessary additional functions in the 'ReporterClass.datacollector' attribute of the `ChildClass`

You could further refactor the way `ReporterClass.datacollector` is build to populate it with parameters - instead, here, additional values are directly added after the call to `super()`.

```
def some_function1(): pass    
def some_function2(): pass
def some_function3(): pass
def some_function4(): pass


class ReporterClass:
    def __init__(self, data_reporter):
        self.data_reporter = data_reporter


class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self._data_reporter = {'Report info 1': some_function1,
                               'Report info 2': some_function2,
                               'Report info 3': some_function3}
        self.datacollector = ReporterClass(self._data_reporter)


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        super().__init__(param1, param2)
        self.datacollector.data_reporter['Report info 4'] = some_function4


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(ParentClass(1, 2).datacollector.data_reporter)
    print(ChildClass(3, 4).datacollector.data_reporter)
```

#### [edit] -----------

You can use args, kwargs if you are finding the handling of many parameters cumbersome, like this:

```
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.param1, self.param2 = args
        self._data_reporter = {'Report info 1': some_function1,
                               'Report info 2': some_function2,
                               'Report info 3': some_function3}
        self.datacollector = ReporterClass(self._data_reporter)


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.datacollector.data_reporter['Report info 4'] = some_function4


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(ParentClass(1, 2).datacollector.data_reporter)
    print(ChildClass(3, 4).datacollector.data_reporter)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way the ChildClass can inherit the same param# from the parent's `__init__`, so param1 and param2 don't need to be explicitly written/repeated in the ChildClass's `__init__`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. In the example posted above, the child class is using the parent's attributes, they are not repeated; the parameters are passed to `super()` as arguments that calls the parent's `__init__`, where they are assigned to the attributes. Those attributes are of the child class, inherited from the parent.

Comment: I've added some edits in the original post, please let me know if it's clear. I searched for a while, but I couldn't find any examples that I was hoping for as in my theorized `ChildClass2` above.

Comment: Thanks, that is a solution very close to what I want. My question is, however, does the `__init__(self, *args)` has to be in both ParentClass and ChildClass? I don't mind spell out all the parameters for initiation once in the ParentClass. I actually prefer it, so that I can write something like `ParentClass(param1=1, param2=2).datacollector.data_reporter`, now I can't with your final suggestion. Is there really no way to keep the parameter specification in the ParentClass, but use the `*args` only in the ChildClass?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, would the following do what you're looking for?

```
class MaybeWorks:
    def __init__(self, num_funcs, *args):
        for k, arg in enumerate(args):
            setattr(self, 'param'+str(k+1), arg)
        data_reporter=dict()
        for k in range(num_funcs):
            data_reporter['Report info '+str(k+1)] = globals()['some_function'+str(k+1)]
        self.datacollector = ReporterClass(data_reporter)
```